# Given a set of arbitrary points, how do I determine a geofence containing those points?

Tags: geometry, geospatial, computational-geometry

The given set of points is arbitrary and not something that will be constant, given this set of points I have a need to determin the proximity which preferably would result in a bezier polygon.

My theory of approaching would be to find the northern most point and find the closest point to the east and south then working around to the west.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the concept you are seeking is the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?
There are many algorithms to compute it, e.g., the beautiful Graham scan, for which you may find code
at [this link](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html).

          
[image: convex hull]

Comment: Is there any problem finding the convex hull of a set of points when the underlying geometry is non Euclidean? In the OP's case, the points lie on the surface of the sphere, thus the algorithm for a points inclusion/exclusion in the current hull surface would need to account for that.

Comment: @Hooked: I didn't even realize his points were on a sphere! When the points lie in one hemisphere, it is easy and much the same.  When the points span more than a hemisphere, then there are complications...

Comment: Wikipedia calls a geofence a _virtual perimeter for a real-world geographic area_, from which I assumed it was over the Earth's surface. I'd quantify your answer to account for this.